# How do I combine objects in a generic list into generic class?

Tags: c#, list, object

So I have a generic list of objects, and I need to combine their properties to get list of sums.

```
public class PickupReport
{
    public int Units { get; set; }
    public int Revenue { get; set; }
    public int Accs { get; set; }
}

public class ReportBase<TReport>
{
    public List<TReport> Reports { get; set; }
    public List<int> Sum 
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<int>{1,2,3}
        }
    }
}
```

So, if I have

```
var reportBase = new ReportBase<PickupReport>();
reportBase.Reports = new List<PickupReport>{

new PickupReport{Units = 1, Revenue = 2, Accs = 3},
new PickupReport{Units = 4, Revenue = 5, Accs = 6},
new PickupReport{Units = 2, Revenue = 3, Accs = 4}

}
```

I need to get and calculate `reportBase.Sum` and it should be `List<int>` with `{7, 10, 13}`

Like `{the sum of property #1 for all objects, the sum of property #2 for all objects, and so on.. }`

Is it possible to do this somehow, given that the number of objects in the list is dynamic? Well, the number of object properties, too, but within the class.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya didn't find any solution with Sum for generic class and list of objects inside it, sorry:(

Comment: So are you saying that you want a generic function that will return a set of summed properties for any object you pass in? Or will the generic object always have those 3 properties?

Comment: as long as you don't define `TReport` (as an interface for example) then this is only possible by reflection. are the properties in `PickupReport` really meant to be private?

Comment: Can you share your code attempt of using Sum Linq method? If I wrote answer for this question I would write with Sum method only. So it will be worth to see why Sum method didn't solve your issue.

Comment: Instead of a list of integers why not make a `PickupReport` that has the sum of the properties.

Comment: @DavidG First variant. Objects of different classes that will be nested in a generic class with this function can have, depending on the class, a different number of properties. And I need to make a function that would sum up all the properties of objects in the list - {the sum of property #1 for all objects, the sum of property #2 for all objects, and so on.. }

Comment: So if you create a `ISummable` interface that exposes a way to add two classes together, then use that as the constraint on `TReport` you'd be able to sum up the reports into one final report.  Then it's up to the individual reports to determine how to sum the properties together.

Comment: so would that mean that the properties could be `double` ? `single` ? `int` ? `short` ? you get the drift ?=!

Comment: @juharr Because I need List like this - {the sum of property #1 for all objects, the sum of property #2 for all objects, and so on.. }

Comment: what if the properties are of type `char` ? you can calculate a sum with those values too, but the interpretation of those numbers might be misleading

Comment: @juharr wow, can you give me an example?

Comment: Why are you using generics if the type of object could be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @MongZhu only int

Then I would suggest to use reflection for this approach. Make it a method rather then a property:

```
public class ReportBase<TReport>
{

    public List<TReport> Reports { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<int> CalculateSum()
    {
        foreach (var element in typeof(TReport).GetProperties())
        {
            if (element.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            {
                yield return Reports.Sum(x => (int)element.GetValue(x));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

This method iterates over all properties that are in the type and if it finds a property of type `int` it will calculate the sum of it from the entire list.

Here is a testprogramm and the result dump from LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var reportBase = new ReportBase<PickupReport>();
    reportBase.Reports = new List<PickupReport>{

    new PickupReport(1,2,3),
    new PickupReport(4,5,6),
    new PickupReport(2,3,4)

    };

    reportBase.CalculateSum().Dump();
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

> just noticed, that objects in my project can have two types of properties, not one

Here is a version where you can add types to a list of allowed sum up types:

```
public class ReportBase<TReport>
{
    public List<TReport> Reports { get; set; }

    List<Type> possibleTypes = new List<Type> {typeof(int), typeof(double)};

    public IEnumerable<double> CalculateSum()
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo element in typeof(TReport).GetProperties())
        {
            if (possibleTypes.Contains(element.PropertyType))
            {
                yield return Reports.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(element.GetValue(x)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can also handle `double`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! That's really great answer and it will be very helpful! But you know, just noticed, that objects in my project can have two types of properties, not one:( Double and int.. Like ```public int Units { get; set; }
        public int Revenue { get; set; }
        public double Accs { get; set; }``` Is it possible to take this into account?

Comment: @AtlasPromotion " just noticed, that objects in my project can have two types of properties, not one"  :D I knew it, and tomorrow there will be a change of requirements and you also get `decimal` added

Comment: @MongZhu don't think so, all stats have only this two types

Comment: @AtlasPromotion I added a version that also can handle `double`. I made it also extensible, so you can add tomorrow another type like `byte` ;)

Comment: @MongZhu Thank you again, really appreciate that:3

Answer (score 1):

This should get you a `List<int>` with the sums of all `int` properties of `TReport`:

```
var properties = typeof(PickupReport).GetProperties();
List<int> sum = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i<properties.Length; ++i)
{
    sum.Add(0);
    if (properties[i].PropertyType == typeof(int))
    {
        foreach (var report in reportBase.Reports)
        {
            sum[i] += (int) properties[i].GetValue(report);
        }
    }
}
```